# Select current DB data in <select> list

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can someone please show me *STEP BY STEP* about how to make the current DB data be "selected" in the dropdown? I do not know anything about JS so I'm having a hard time right now.

This is the whole js script im using. http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/
The html

```
    <body>
        <div align="center">
   <hr/>            
<br/>Select Country (with states):
            <select id="country" name="country"></select>
            <br />State:
            <select name="state" id="state"></select>
            <br/>
            <br />Select Country (without states):
            <select id="country2" name="country2"></select>
            <br />
            <script language="javascript">
                populateCountries("country", "state");
                populateCountries("country2");
            </script>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: you want to populate select based on other select field??

Comment: When you say: _" how to make the current DB data be 'selected' "_ What do you mean exactly? Do you mean you want a country pre-selected when page loads, or do you want it after some type of click event? please be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the data from database and then make the selections as you click on the next `<select>` accordingly?

Comment: Also, do you really mean DB as in Database? From what I see you're just using Arrays.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I want the db data to be shwon in the dropdown. php/html -> <select name="myselect">

<option value="" <?php if($word== "hello") echo "selected"; ?> hello</option>

Comment: @helpmescript you shud use ajax for that, onchange call ajax, and display the results

Comment: @CodeGodie exactly. i want the country to be pre-selected when the page loads. yes i mean database :O  Sorry man english is pretty bad hah

Comment: ok, and how do we know what country needs to be pre-selected?

Comment: @CodeGodie idk. Thats the problem :/ ill take a look at ur solotion later. Thanks :D

Comment: What do you mean you dont know? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create another function in JS:

```
function preSelect(ElementId, selected_val) {
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(ElementId);
    countryElement.value= selected_val;
}
```

Then in your code you can run the function in this order

```
<script language="javascript">
    populateCountries("country", "state");
    populateCountries("country2");
    preSelect("country", "Albania"); // <-- Here you specify the country you want
</script>
```

**Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eRv2W/815/)**

Comment: Then what about the states? JS cant catch what value the state is then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value to select.

```
document.getElementById('country').value = <db value>;
```